# online iPhone simulator testing

Tags: iphone, device

I want to test my website on iPhone.

However, I do not have iPhone at my working place.

So, is there any way to test it online?

Or, I can download app to test it.

Also, my current development environment is windows 10.

So, I can not use xCode to test my website.

Best regards,

Comment: How about in Chrome Developer Tools? You can select an iPhone there.

Comment: Please don't ask for tools on stackoverflow, it tends to lead to [opinionated answers and spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The previously mentioned also encourages that you [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and whatever has been done to try and solve it.